# Converting Excel Data to a Chart in HTML dynamically

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

Is it possible to be able to upload an excel document with varying ranges of data, and have that data dynamically displayed in a basic form of chart(bar, pie, etc.) on our company website.

After doing some research I figured the only two possible ways to maybe do something like this is to use a very complicated macro in VBA or a Javascript parser to read the data and display it then. The data that will eventually go in here will have sensitive information so I cannot use google charts or anything like that.

Comment: as far as I know, there is no easy way for it. You need to write custom code for it. You can store the chart engine locally and avoid sending any data outside your organization. Have a look here: http://ashuvba.blogspot.com/2015/01/java-script-chart-in-excel.html

Comment: You can check [telerik kendo-ui](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui)

Answer (score 1):

This problem has to be divided into two parts. 
One -part is to gather and process the information needed to display the chart.
Second - This is the easiest, a way to display a chart in HTML. For this, you can use [www.c3js.org](http://c3js.org/) javascript library to display the chart in HTML.

Regarding part one, it depends in which technology is built your website.
For example, If it is in php, you will need to find a library in php, which can read and parse excel files. 
Then you have to create a service in your website, where the data is going to be provided. For example, 
www.yourcompany.com/provideChartData.php

You can format the response as json format.

Once you have solved that, you only have to call the service from your page, and the data will be dynamically displayed. You can call it using [jquery library](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for javascript ($.post("www.yourcompany.com/provideChartData.php",function (data) { code to display chart ....}))

Answer (score 0):

There is no real easy way to do this that I have found. I have had to manually parse these things in the past but there are some libraries out there for node that might help you.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-xlsx

You can also export form excel as CSV. When you do this, me sure to set the custom separator to something other than ',' and you should be fine to import it into a large array and get the data/charts you need.

https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

Hope that helps.